# Почему при перенаправлении по регекспу nginx отдаёт octet-stream?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx, mime

Пытаюсь настроить перенаправления для Codeigniter так, чтобы работал URL вида `localhost/codeigniter/class`, так  `localhost/codeigniter/class`. URL подобного вида используются также в Drupal 8, поэтому решил сделать перенаправление по регэкспу:

```
location ~ /(drupal|codeigniter)/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite8;
    }

location @rewrite8 {
        rewrite ^/(drupal|codeigniter) /$1/index.php;
    }
```

Однако при переходе на страницу мне предлагают скачать файл (в заголовке ответа MIME-тип выглядит как `octet-stream`).

Если не использовать регэкспов:

```
location /codeigniter/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite8;
    }
```

то всё работает нормально и отдаётся `text/html`.

С чем это может быть связано и как мне сделать правильное перенаправление?

UPD. Полный конфиг:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /codeigniter/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite8;
    }

    location /drupal7/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite7;
    }

    location @rewrite7 {
        rewrite  ^/drupal7/(.*)$ /drupal7/index.php?q=$1;
    }
    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

    location ~ \.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location @rewrite8 {
        rewrite ^/(drupal|codeigniter) /$1/index.php;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

Comment: Покажите весь конфиг сервера

Comment: @AlexeyTen, добавил

Comment: А что в этом файле? Исходник на php?

Comment: @AlexeyTen в том, который он предлагает скачать? Не проверял

Comment: Ну так проверьте

Comment: @AlexeyTen Да, отдаётся исходник

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочитайте как nginx обрабатывает location http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

В вашем случае до изменения, запрос за `/codeigniter/index.php` обрабатывался в `location ~ \.php`, потому что `location` заданный регулярным выражением «побеждает» обычный префиксный `location /codeigniter/`.

После изменения, оба `location` стали регулярными выражениями и в этом случае побеждает первый подошедший, т.е. `location ~ /(drupal|codeigniter)/`.

Сами авторы nginx считают (и я с ними согласен), что не нужно без нужны усложнять конфиг регурярками если можно обойтись парой строчек.

Если же вам всё-таки хочется, то во-первых, поменяйте эти `location` местами, а во-вторых, поправьте новый блок на `location ~ ^/(drupal|codeigniter)/`